# Doctrine conditional associations

Tags: php, mysql, doctrine, associations

I have the tables `agents`, `users`, `accounts`

Account has `owner` and `owner_type` fields. There are two `owner_type`'s: `1` for agents, `2` for internal users. Owner represented by `owner_id` field.

So `{account_id: 1, owner_id: 1, owner_id: 1}` refers to the `agent_id` = 1 in the `agents` table.

And `{account_id: 1, owner_id: 1, owner_id: 2}` refers to the `user_id` = 1 in the `agents` table.

What's the best practice with describing metadata in Doctrine (I use XML)?

Comment: Inheritance: Use an AbstractUser which is extended by agents & users, when retrieved doctrine will map to the correct type (in this case no need to save to db the owner_type)

Comment: @mboullouz hm, but if I have some special owner types that doesn't refer to the table. `owner_type` = 3, `owner_id` = null for internal stuff? Should I create objects for every `owner_type` that extends abstractType?

Comment: to use doctrine magic, yes you should create a new type which extends abstractUser, but if user types are "dynamic" or "infinit" better to keep you current way, but every time you need to load owner then test on owner_type then load the correct type (which is what doctrine do in background using a discriminator field)

Comment: @mboullouz thx, inheritance works perfectly!